# Pass Ajax response array to Chart.js

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, chart.js

I have a problem using the array passed from php through ajax.
I need to put the data into a Chart.js Graph.

My Ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: { action: 'hfwpGetGraph' },
    success: function(response) {
        var myLabels = [];
        var myData = [];

        for(var i in response) {
            myLabels.push(response[i].Date);
            myData.push(response[i].DiaLevel);
        }
        <Chart.js code>
    } // End Success
})  // End Ajax
```

If I display my array every row it looks like this:

```
[{"ID":"17","UserID":"29","Date":"2016-09-25","Systolic1":"50","Systolic2":"0","Systolic3":"45","Diastolic1":"48","Diastolic2":"0","Diastolic3":"51","SysAverage":"0","DiaAverage":"0","SysLevel":"0","SysText":"","DiaLevel":"0","DiaText":""},
```

If I display "myLabels" or "myData" they both shows:

```
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

What am I doing wrong....??

Note: My php array is passed like this:

```
echo json_encode($graphData);
```

Regards
Flemming

Comment: Try to acces for(var i in response[0]) and verify if your response array is correct

Comment: Did you try using the each loop, since for-in is typically used to loop through objects

Comment: The "for(var i in response[0])" just gave an empty array.

Comment: Do you mean each like this :

$.each(response, function(entry) {
                        console.log(entry);
                    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding the "parseJSON" after the "success".

```
success: function(response) {
     var json = $.parseJSON(response);
```

But I don't understand the full concept of the solution.
Most examples I've seen parsing an array() from php to javascript through ajax don't use the parseJSON conversion.

They just work with the response as if it already were an array and not a string.